# compile/recompile mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am using AWS RDS MySQL(8.x). It is giving me trouble every time when even I do some update/modification in stored procs. I need to recompile it before running it. I can see this recompile option on my IDE/studio as it is an enterprise version. but my other colleagues are using some other IDE/Studio/Client where they are not finding this recompile option.

Is there any query/command to recompile MySQL proc. and if command s there, I can put that in the proc so that it recompiles every time when I run it.

Thank you

Comment: If you change the stored procedure you have to run it to save it. There is no option to compile it when it's called - that would be a terrible idea in  a production db - imagine the fuss if the compile failed during the online day..

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In my case, it is not mandatory that I need to recompile my proc every time it runs but I need a query/command with which I can recompile the proc.